# How do I set up a private GIT repository on a Windows machine and access it from a Mac using SourceTree and Bitvise SSH Server?

Tags: git, macos, ssh, windows-10, atlassian-sourcetree

I have a private Windows-10 PC on my local network and I want to use it to house a GIT repository to be accessed from my Mac via SSH, using SourceTree and Bitvise SSH Server. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharing my solution, as it cost some effort and there were some non-obvious steps. In the outline below, my Windows PC is named *ineke* and I use an account named *bill* on the Mac and a local account named *bill* on Windows. The two names don't have to be the same of course.

Using Windows-10 Creators Update, MacOS Sierra 10.12.5, Git 2.6.2 (free), SourceTree 2.5.3 (free) and BitVise SSH Server 7.32 (free).

---

1. Install Git on remote Windows PC. [Probably optional: Check version of git on Mac (git -- version in Terminal) and install the same version on remote server. In SourceTree on Mac, select this version (Preferences -> git ) ].
2. In Terminal on Mac, use ssh-keygen to create a private/public keypair 
   in /Users/bill/.ssh/id_rsa.pub  Remember the passphrase.
3. Configure free BitVise SSH Server on remote server with public key of client, in a **local** Windows account called bill. Use ‘Open easy settings’.
4. On remote server, ensure the System path contains c:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core (or similar)
   thereby allowing access to git-upload-pack and git-receive-pack.
   (Right-click This PC -> Properties ->Advanced system settings ->Environment variables -> System variables -> Path.)
5. On the Mac, ensure the remote server is referenced in /etc/hosts. Use 
   sudo nano /etc/hosts, do the edit, then 
   sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder.
6. Test SSH from Terminal on the Mac: ssh bill@ineke – this should bring you to the PC command line.
7. If problems with SSH test, try deleting Users/bill/.ssh/known_hosts.
8. On private Windows server (ineke) create empty directory  in login account bill:  bill/GitRepositories/Xyz.git/
9. Right-click on folder bill/GitRepositories/Xyz.git and select Git Bash Here. Then at GitBash command line enter:
   git init  -- bare (to create empty repository).

NOTE: If Git Bash Here is not available, run GitBash.exe and enter
git init -- bare ~/GitRepositories/Xyz.git

10. On Mac, move Xyz directory, containing files involved, to Desktop and, in the place where it was, create an empty directory of the same name (Xyz).
11. In the Desktop Xyz  directory, delete any and all hidden .git files. (Use Terminal -> showFiles/hideFiles to view hidden files : http://ianlunn.co.uk/articles/quickly-showhide-hidden-files-mac-os-x-mavericks/).
12. On Mac in SourceTree, click on New Repository > Clone from URL.
13. On Clone a Repository screen, for Source URL enter
    ssh://bill@ineke/~/GitRepositories/Xyz.git and then click in Destination Path. The message ‘This is a Git repository’ will appear.

NOTE: If instead you see ‘Not a Git repository’, check the server’s Path.

14. In Destination Path, navigate to the empty Xyz directory, then enter a Name and click Clone. A local Xyz repository will be created in the Xyz directory.
15. In SourceTree create a .gitignore file to exclude unwanted files. Double-click on Xyz -> Settings -> Advanced -> Edit. To edit the global ignore list, go to SourceTree -> Preferences -> Git -> Edit.
16. Copy all the files in the Xyz directory on the desktop to the empty Xyz directory.
17. In SourceTree, double-click on the Xyz repository. In the window that opens, click Pending Files then click Commit Message.  Enter a comment and click  ‘Push changes immediately to origin/master’. Click Commit.